# add Polymer element to the Google Web Designer

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, google-web-designer

There is a possibility to add your custom element to the Google Web Designer.
To do this it's needed to create some files :

1. js file(required) - it's a custom element itself(registration and definition)
2. css (optional) - styles,applied to the element
3. manifest.json(required) - this file tells GWD how to use custom element

As you see,GWD wants a js file,but when we creating element with Polymer we get HTML file.So question is: is it possible do tell GWD that we have HTML file not js so that GWD added this file using HTML Import? And if yes,how to do this?

And another moment:there is polyfill to the custom elements,shadow dom and so on made by Polymer team webcomponents.js,when I add this file to GWD project all breaks. 
Do anybody knows what to do add this file in a write way?